# Error array output

Tags: java, for-loop

Whenever I try to create a method for my array, I get an error on the line containing 
`(int i =0; i < list.length; i++)`.  A red line is displayed under `list.length`, but when I don't put it under a method there are no errors. How do I fix this? I am required to use a method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    System.out.println("Sergio Borja, Class Meeting Time: Tue/Thu 1:30-2:50pm");
    Movie[] list = new Movie[6];
    list[0] = new Animated("Batman Begins", "Zack Snyder" , 2006, 4000000000.0, 4, 3000.0);
    list[1] = new Animated("Batman v Superman", "Jack Smith", 2016, 250200.0, 3, 20000.0);
    list[2] = new Documentary("The Lone Ranger", "Spike Lee", 2002, 2000000.0, 1000, 4000.0);
    list[3] = new Documentary("Cowboys", "Bob lies", 1992, 5000000.0, 1050 , 2000.0);
    list[4] = new Drama ("Karate Kid","Jackie Chan", 1998, 2000000000.0, 60000000.0, 15.25);
    list[5] = new Drama ("The Amazing SpiderMan", "Bobby Smith", 2014, 150000000.0, 20000000.0, 14.50);

}
    public void printMovieInfo(Movie[] Movie)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < list.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%s", list[i].toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the `list` coming from?

Comment: I made several subclasses and the parent class is Movie

Answer (score 1):

You are passing in an array named `Movie` (which is also the name of the `class`), but trying to use an array named `list`. Change

```
public void printMovieInfo(Movie[] Movie)
```

to

```
public void printMovieInfo(Movie[] list)
```

Comment: Worked out perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

printMovieInfo doesn't know `list`. Replace it with the correct parameter name, i.e. `Movie` (and rename it with a lowercase once it works).

Comment: I am required to name my method printMovieInfo. Is there another way?

Comment: Don't rename the method, change `Movie[] Movie` with `Movie[] list`.

Answer (score 0):

Your *list* variable is located in your main method, which is not visible to your printMovieInfo method. use the movie variable you have in your argument. Additionally, add the printMovieInfo call from your main.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    System.out.println("Sergio Borja, Class Meeting Time: Tue/Thu 1:30-2:50pm");
    Movie[] list = new Movie[6];
    list[0] = new Animated("Batman Begins", "Zack Snyder" , 2006, 4000000000.0, 4, 3000.0);
    list[1] = new Animated("Batman v Superman", "Jack Smith", 2016, 250200.0, 3, 20000.0);
    list[2] = new Documentary("The Lone Ranger", "Spike Lee", 2002, 2000000.0, 1000, 4000.0);
    list[3] = new Documentary("Cowboys", "Bob lies", 1992, 5000000.0, 1050 , 2000.0);
    list[4] = new Drama ("Karate Kid","Jackie Chan", 1998, 2000000000.0, 60000000.0, 15.25);
    list[5] = new Drama ("The Amazing SpiderMan", "Bobby Smith", 2014, 150000000.0, 20000000.0, 14.50);

    printMovieInfo(list);  // <--- here is the call to print movie info

}

public static void printMovieInfo(Movie[] movie)
{
        for (int i =0; i < movie.length; i++){
            System.out.printf("%s", movie[i].toString());
}
```

Comment: Hmm i get an error saying I need to change my method to static?

Comment: ah correct, main method is static and you need to change the printMovieInfo to static as well.  Since static method can only call/invoke other methods that are static.